# Search for the certain text in log

Tags: file, logging, search, report

how can I search for text in log file, that looks like:

```yaml
04 03 2007 13 37 213.220.251.22 PROPFIND
04 03 2007 13 37 213.220.251.22 PROPFIND
04 03 2007 13 37 213.220.251.22 PROPFIND
04 03 2007 13 37 213.220.251.22 PROPFIND
First is day, month, year, hour, minute, IP, operation.
```

I have to find only for REPORT logs with time 9:00 to 13:00.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this using unix `awk` as shown below:

```
awk '/^04 03 2007 9/,/04 03 2007 13*/' logs.txt
```